# Links in bar charts (charts.js)

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

I am very new to charts.js and I was wondering if it is possible to make bars in bar charts clickable links? I saw that it was possible for doughnut charts. I'd appreciate any help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know you required bar chart but I have used in doughnut chart
I hope this will help you..

find example here:- https://jsfiddle.net/ha19ozqy/

```
document.getElementById("myChart").onclick = function(evt){
            var activePoints = myChart.getElementsAtEvent(evt);
            var firstPoint = activePoints[0];
            var label = myChart.data.labels[firstPoint._index];
            var value = myChart.data.datasets[firstPoint._datasetIndex].data[firstPoint._index];
            if (firstPoint !== undefined)
                alert(label + ": " + value);
        };
```